# How do I normalize the pixel value of an image to 0~1?

Tags: python, image, numpy, normalization

The type of my **train_data** is '**Array of unit 16**'. The size is **(96108,7,7)**. Therefore, there are 96108 images.

The image is different from the general image. My image has a sensor of 7x7 and 49 pixels contain the number of detected lights. And one image is the number of light detected for 0 to 1 second. Since the sensor detects randomly for a unit time, the maximum values of the pixel are all different.

If the max value of all images is 255, I can do 'train data/255', but I can't use the division because the max value of the image I have is all different.
I want to make the pixel value of all images 0 to 1.
What should I do?

Comment: `I can't use the division because the max value of the image I have is all different` This part of your question is ambiguous. Are you saying that some of your images have a different range (i.e. 8-bit or 12-bit depth) and others have a different range/bit-depth? Or are you saying that the individual images (train_data[idx]) have different values?

If the former, do you know which images have what depth? If the latter, do you aim for a normalization scheme such that the possible range of each image is normalized to [0, 1], or one where the actual range of each image is normalized to [0, 1]?

Comment: On the contrary, the max value *doesn't* change. It's defined by the color depth of the image format and specified in the image's header. If all images use the same format, the max value is the same for all, and typically 255.

Comment: I'm sorry.
The image I mentioned is different from the general image.
My image has a sensor of 7x7 and 49 pixels contain the number of detected lights. And one image is the number of light detected for 0 to 1 second. Since the sensor detects randomly for a unit time, the maximum values of the pixel are all different.

Comment: You'll have to explain this in the question. How is this different from any other image though? Different shutter speeds result in different brightness in cameras too. Darker subjects result in lower pixel values. When image tools normalize pictures they calculate both the min and max value of an image and map these to 0-1 or 0-255.

Comment: @김수환 only you know the intricacies of your data though. People have posted two answers, one that shows how to normalize in the photographic sense, one that just normalizes the vector. We can't tell which is better

Comment: In image recognition applications pictures can get through quite a bit of preprocessing - not just normalization but edge detection as well, to make the important features more prominent.

Comment: 3Dspatial user gave me the answer I wanted.
My explanation was insufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=(96108, 7, 7))
data_min = np.min(data, axis=(1,2), keepdims=True)
data_max = np.max(data, axis=(1,2), keepdims=True)

scaled_data = (data - data_min) / (data_max - data_min)
```

EDIT: I have voted for the other answer since that is a cleaner way (in my opinion) to do it, but the principles are the same.

EDIT v2: I saw the comment and I see the difference. I will rewrite my code so it is "cleaner" with less extra variables but still correct using min/max:

```
data -= data.min(axis=(1,2), keepdims=True)
data /= data.max(axis=(1,2), keepdims=True)
```

First the minimum value is moved to zero, thereafter one can take the maximum value to get the full range (max-min) of the specific image.

After this step `np.array_equal(data, scaled_data) = True`.

Comment: On the contrary, this is the correct one because it also takes care of the minimum. If you nomralize only using max the image will either darken or get washed out. When image tools normalize pictures they use the image's min, max (and midpoint among others) to map the image's pixel range to 0-255

Comment: It was found that using the minimum and maximum values had higher accuracy than using only the maximum values.  It's a surprise.

Answer (score 9):

**Contrast Normalization** (or contrast stretch) should not be confused with **Data Normalization** which maps data between 0.0-1.0.

---

### Data Normalization

We use the following formula to normalize data. The *min()* and *max()* values are the possible minimum and maximum values supported within the type of data.

[image]

When we use it with images, *x* is the whole image and *i* is an individual pixel of that image. If you are using an 8-bit image the *min()* and *max()* values become 0 and 255 respectively. **This should not be confused with the minimum and maximum values presented within your image in question.**

To convert an 8-bit image into a floating-point image, As min() value reaches 0,  the simple math is *image/255.*

```
img = img/255
```

NumPy methods likes to output arrays in 64-bit floating-point by default. To effectively test methods applied to 8-bit images with NumPy, an 8-bit array is required as the input:

```
image = np.random.randint(0,255, (7,7),  dtype=np.uint8)
normalized_image = image/255
```

When we examine the output of the above two lines we can see the maximum value of the image is 252 which has now mapped to 0.9882352941176471 on the 64-bit normalized image.

[image]

However, in most cases, you wouldn't need a 64-bit image. You can output (or in other words cast) it to 32-bit (or 16-bit) using the following code. If you try to cast it to 8-bit it will throw an error. Using '/' for division is a shorthand for *np.true_divide* but lacks the ability to define the output data format.

```
normalized_image_2 = np.true_divide(image, 255, dtype=np.float32)
```

The properties of the new array is shown below. You can see the number of digits are now reduced and 252 has been remapped to 0.9882353.

[image]

### Contrast Normalization

The method [shown by @3dSpatialUser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70783585/7418298) effectively does a partial contrast normalization, meaning it stretches the intensities of the image within the available intensity range. Test it with an 8-bit array with the following code.

```
c_image = np.random.randint(64,128, (7,7),  dtype=np.uint8)
cn_image = (c_image - c_image.min()) / (c_image.max()- c_image.min())
```

Contrast is now stretched mapping minimum contrast of 64 to 0.0 and maximum 127 to 1.0.

[image]

The formula for contrast normalization is shown below.

[image]

Using the above formula with NumPy and to remap data back to the 8-bit input format after contrast normalization, the image should be multiplied by 255, then change the data type back to unit8:

```
cn_image_correct = (c_image - c_image.min()) / (c_image.max()- c_image.min()) * 255
cn_image_correct = cn_image_correct.astype(np.int8)
```

64 is now mapped to 0 and 174 is mapped to 255 stretching the contrast.

[image]

### Where the confusion arise

In most applications, the intensity values of an image are spread close to their minima and maxima. Hence, when we apply the normalization formula using the min and max values presented within the image, instead of the min max of the available range, it will output a better looking image (in most cases) within the 0.0-1.0 range, which effectively does normalize both data and contrast at the same time. Also, image editing software perform gamma corrections or remapping when switching between image data types 8/16/32-bits.

Answer (score 3):

You can gather the maximum values with [`np.ndarray.max`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html) across multiple axes: here `axis=1` and `axis=2` (i.e. on each image individually). Then normalize the initial array with it. To avoid having to broadcast this array of maxima yourself, you can use the `keepdims` option:

```
>>> x = np.random.rand(96108,7,7)

>>> x.max(axis=(1,2), keepdims=True).shape
(96108, 1, 1)
```

While `x.max(axis=(1,2))` alone would have returned an array shaped `(96108,)`...

Such that you can then do:

```
>>> x /= x.max(axis=(1,2), keepdims=True)
```

Comment: While this normalize individual images, it will also distort them. Images that are naturally darker or lighter will end up too dark or washed out. Image normalization eg in Photoshop, also uses the minimum value to ensure this doesn't happen

Comment: From the OP's comments though, this doesn't seem to be a regular image. Without more information this is as valid as the other answer